# Cauchy's Theorem Question

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a question about Cauchy's theorem in the book I'm reading:

Let $C$ be a closed, smooth and simple curve bounding a region $D$ and $f=u+iv$. Then $\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_C(u+iv)(dx+idy)=\int_C(udx-vdy)+i\int_C(vdx+udy)$. Using Cauchy-Riemann equations on $D$ and $C$, both integrands are exact, and so the integrals are intependent of $C$, and hence $\int_Cf(z)dz=0$.

My question is in using the CR equations to show the integrands are exact. I understand what the author is saying, but isn't he also implicitly assuming that the region $D$ is contractible? The author is saying if $\omega=Pdx+Qdy$, and $P_y=Q_x$, then $\omega=df$ (i.e. exact). But I know this doesn't hold in all spaces and depends on the topology of the space. It's equivalent to saying $\nabla\times F=0\implies F=\nabla f$, but this isn't true on the punctured plane, as $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}<-y,x>$ shows. It seems like the the region $D$ needs the additional requirement that closed forms are exact, and this is guaranteed by Poincare's Lemma for contractible spaces.

Am I correct, or just confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,$D$ contractible/simply connected... is required. Think in $f(z) = 1/z$ in the unit disk minus the origin. In fact, is essentially the *same* counterexample that your counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that while I was reading. The imaginary part of the integral is the same as the integral in my example above. I was just confused as to why the author chose to omit that condition.